# PHP Spreadsheet - Header image

Tags: php, image, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

I am doing a project in which I use the PHP Spreadsheet library, more info here.

I need to add an image, a jpeg file, in the header of the .xlsx document. For this I am using part of the example code from the official documentation. In this way:

```
// Create a New Excel
    $spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();    
    $drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooterDrawing();
    $drawing->setName('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
    $drawing->setPath('app/files/images/example.jpeg');
    $drawing->setHeight(36);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->addImage($drawing, \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooter::IMAGE_HEADER_LEFT);
```

At the moment the image does not appear and I have not found any error in the code that I use or in the server log, it is a copy of the original, so the doubts that arise are if there is an incompatibility issue or something.

UPDATE:

I have done a test. With this code I have added an image in a cell:

```
    $drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
    $drawing->setName('Paid');
    $drawing->setDescription('Paid');
    $drawing->setPath('app/files/images/example.jpeg'); /* put your path and image here */
    $drawing->setCoordinates('A1');
    $drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
```

It's works fine to use in cell because it's not works in header :(

Please Could you help me?

Comment: Are you sure the path to the image is correct? Have you tried using a full absolute path from the server root?

Comment: Yes because if not the log file show an error.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooterDrawing();
$drawing->setName('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
$drawing->setPath('app/files/images/example.jpeg');
$drawing->setHeight(25);
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->addImage($drawing, \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\HeaderFooter::IMAGE_HEADER_RIGHT);

// Set header
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&L&"Verdana,Negrita"&8HEADER TEXT&R&G');
```

After it sets the image object they is to set in OddHeader using codes:

$R -> To right align
$G -> Insert image

More info [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/).